# What is requirements for a python project that uses curses?

Tags: python, setuptools, ncurses, pypi

I'm new to packaging a program using Pypi. I followed [a tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but it doesn't say much about requirements.

In my project I used some packages like:

```
import datetime, time
from time import sleep
import sys, os
import datetime
import pickle
import shlex
import re
import textwrap
import json
import newspaper #This is a github project

import curses as cur # This must work on both linux and windows
from curses import wrapper
from curses.textpad import rectangle
from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from appdirs import *
```

First, I don't know which one of them must be in `requirements.txt`.

newspaper3k is a github project but has a pypi package [here](https://pypi.org/project/newspaper3k/). The same about `appdirs`.

However, the main required package is `curses`. It must work on both Windows and Linux. I guess in Windows, there is a package called `windows-curses`. What about Linux? and How setup knows to install which? Please guide me, particularly on `curses`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install a python package with its dependencies, you don't need to list them all. Pip will resolve and install them too. For installing `newspaper3k` you only need to run the following

```
pip install newspaper3k
```

and pip will take care of the rest.

With regards to `ncurses`, it is part of the standard python packages. You can find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

`requirements.txt` is a way for specifying project dependencies. It is a simple text file listing the required libraries. It comes handy in managing appropriate library versions. For instance, you could add the following line

```
newspaper3k==0.2.8
```

and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can read more on `requirements.txt` [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Comment: You mean since I imported them, then pip install any required file without me specifying them in requirement.txt?

Comment: You need to pip install the dependencies and then import. Even if you specify them in `requirements.txt`, you still need to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` before running the code. The safest to manage dependencies is through virtualenvs, [for instance](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: How can I make my python file an executable one, because it was my initial aim, but later I found pypi just package my files as package to be imported in python, I want it to be a software one can run...

Comment: I guess that this is the solution: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html (right?) to create a script which calls the main function

Comment: I have not been using python in this way. [This](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) might provide a solution.